# PHP Syntax error with variables inside string

Tags: php

I have tried swapping between single and double quotes, and I have tried printing each line with `echo` without `<<<END END;`, but none worked.
My code:

```
if ($numRows > 0) {
   while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
     echo <<<END
     <tr>
     <td scope="row">' . $row["id"]. '</td>
     <td> ' . $row["name"] .'</td>
     <td> '.$row["gender"] .'</td>
     <td> '.$row["email"] .'</td>
     <td> '.$row["program"] .'</td>
     <td> '.$row["comments"] .'</td>
     <td> '.$row["summer"] .'</td>
     </tr>
     END;
   }
 } else {
   echo '0 results. No students enrolled.';
} 
    echo '</tbody></div></table>';
```

The error says:

> ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in L:\wamp\www\project\admin.php on line 128

with line 128 being
     `<td scope="row">' . $row["id"]. '</td>`

Comment: Show your SQL query...

Comment: Try this `<td scope="row"><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>`

Comment: Mixing heredoc, quotes, choose one style please.